# Tiempo de computación aumenta exponencialmente al aumentar el tamaño de la muestra

Tags: python, python-2.7, eficiencia

Tengo un código que simula un juego de señales en una microsociedad. Cada agente opera como una función de diferentes parámentros (entre los que están "b", "x", "m").

El caso es que al aumentar el número de simulaciones que realizo el tiempo de la simulación crece exponencialmente, generándome problemas al utilizar listas de diccionarios muy largas o querer realizar un número alto de simulaciones. Por ejemplo:

```
muestras = [d for d in samples for _ in range(100)]
```

Me gustaría encontrar el modo de obtener el mismo csv file, pero bajar el tiempo de la simulación. Quizá el problema se encuentre en los loops y cálculos que hago al escribir el csv file, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo más eficientemente.

El código que utilizo es similar al que copio abajo. Se aprecian sugerencias.

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
from collections import deque
import csv
import math



class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                          for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                          for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()

    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                (0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                (0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))

        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                         for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}


def entropy(lista):
    N = sum(lista)
    probs = (freq/N for freq in lista if freq>0)
    return -sum(x * math.log(x, 2) for x in probs)

def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
    emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                       [(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                       [(1, 4), (2, 3)],
                       [(1, 3), (2, 4)]]

    patron = 1
    s = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    muestras = [{'b': 0.0, 'x': 0.0, 'm': 0.02},
               {'b': 0.1, 'x': 0.0, 'm': 0.02}]

    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1000)]

    simulaciones = 10

    estadisticas = {jugador: {muestra: {senal: [0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1)]
                                        for senal in senales}
                              for muestra in range(len(muestras))}
                    for jugador in jugadores}

    for mu in range(len(muestras)):
        for _ in range(simulaciones):
            juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'],
                            muestras[mu]['m'])
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

        with open('datos.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                                quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(['Muestra', 'Jugador', 'Ronda', 'Patron', 'b', 'x', 'm'] + senales + ['sumpop'] + ['entpop'])
 # Escribiendo las estadisticas para cada jugador, ronda y muestra
            for jugador in jugadores:
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1):
                        aux = [estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                        aux1 = [estadisticas[1][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                        aux2 = [estadisticas[2][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                        aux3 = [estadisticas[3][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                        aux4 = [estadisticas[4][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
# Lista que contiene los sumatorios de cada tipo de senales producidas a nivel de la poblacion global en cada muestra y ronda
                        summation_pop = []
                        for i in range(len(aux1)):
                            summation_pop.append(
                                aux1[i] + aux2[i] + aux3[i] + aux4[i])
                        writer.writerow([mu + 1, jugador, ronda, patron, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'],
                                         muestras[mu]['m']] + aux + [summation_pop] + [entropy(summation_pop)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: La creación de esa lista de diccionarios apenas tarda 8 microsegundos en la prueba que acabo de hacer. No puede ser esa la causa de que te vaya lento, ni mucho menos de que se quede corriendo indefinidamente. Algún bug tienes en otro sitio. Si la lista fuese mucho más larga, podría darte problemas de memoria, más que de tiempo. En ese caso cambia corchetes por paréntesis y tienes un generador, que va creando los elementos a medida que se los pidas en un `for`, de forma _lazy_ y sin requerir crearlos todos de antemano y tenerlos guardados en una lista.

Comment: Me temo que la lista es larga. Contiene cien diccionarios con diferentes combianciones de parámetros.

Comment: Prueba entonces a usar una expresión generadora en lugar de una lista. Como mínimo aliviará problemas de memoria (que a su vez podrían causar problemas de rendimiento, si el operativo empieza a hacer _swapping_, pero dudo que esa sea la causa). Convendría que intentaras hacer un _profiling_ del programa, quizás con una lista más pequeña para evitar que se te cuelgue, a ver si detectas dónde está perdiendo el tiempo. Pero insisto que no creo que sea en la creación de la lista.

Comment: He detectado que al aumentar el tamaño de la lista el tiempo de ejcución va aumentando exponencialmente. Pero no doy con la clave de lo que pasa.

Comment: No entiendo gran cosa de lo que hace el código, pero entiendo que el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse `Partida.jugar()` es más o menos una constante, que no debería depender del tamaño de la lista `muestras`. Veo una cosa potencialmente sospechosa, y es que en el bucle `for mu in range(len(muestras))` de `main()`, tienes una escritura de un fichero csv, el cual por tanto se está reescribiendo en cada muestra. Y dentro de la escriura del fichero hay otra vez un `for mu in range(len(muestras)):` por lo que el tiempo de ejecución crece cuadráticamente (como poco) con el número de muestras.

Comment: He comprobado que en efecto la lista de diccionarios no tiene nada que ver con la ralentización progresiva que se nota cuando se aumenta el número de simulaciones. He comprobado que cuando duplico el tamaño de la muestra el tiempo de simulación no se duplica, sino que aumenta exponencialmente.

Comment: Cuando dices "exponencialmente" ¿podrías precisar aproximadamente la tendencia? Es decir, al aumentar N, el tiempo aumenta como N^2, N^3... (en cuyo caso no es exponencialmente, sino más bien "polinómicamente") O si crece como A^N, siendo A un número fijo, en cuyo casi sí estaríamos hablando de exponencial. Como indiqué en un comentario previo, yo esperaría N^2 como consecuencia de los bucles anidados en los que iteras sobre las muestras. No queda claro tampoco por qué creas el csv dentro del bucle principal, puesto que siempre abres el mismo fichero, sobreescribiendo al anterior.

Comment: En una versión del código que utilizo (utilizando 8 jugadores y tan solo una combinación de parámetros, es decir, un diccionario en la lista): una simulación con 100 muestras (for i in range(100)) dura unos 20 segundos. 200 muestras duran unos 83 segundos. 300 duran unos 170 segundos. Por lo tanto, se me parece más a un polinomio del tipo time=n^3. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84745/discussion-between-abulafia-and-pyring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez se ha suministrado el código completo, es posible hacer con él algunos experimentos.

Lo primero, he añadido lo siguiente al principio:

```
from random import seed
seed(1)
```

Eso garantiza que todas las ejecuciones que haga generarán el mismo resultado. Lo usaré para comprobar que el fichero `.csv` que se genera es el mismo aún cuando haya hecho cambios en el código para mejorar la eficiencia.

Lo siguiente, usar el módulo `cProfile` de python para cronometrar el tiempo que se ejecuta el programa y en qué función es en la que más tiempo invierte. Este módulo puede usarse para generar un sencillo informe de texto en la terminal, así:

```
$ python -m cProfile -s cumtime demo.py
```

Veo que la ejecución tarda unos 94 segundos en terminar en mi ordenador. La opción `-s cumtime` ordena el resultado de mayor a menor tiempo acumulado de ejecución.  Esto significa que si una función tarda en ejecutarse sólo 0.01 segundos, pero se ha ejecutado 10000 veces, su tiempo total será de 10 segundos.

Puedo ver que comienza diciendo lo siguiente (`demo.py` es el nombre bajo el que he guardado tu programa):

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      5/1    0.000    0.000   94.129   94.129 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000   94.129   94.129 demo.py:1(<module>)
        1   29.215   29.215   94.121   94.121 demo.py:79(main)
  6402000   20.560    0.000   20.560    0.000 {method 'writerow' of '_csv.writer' objects}
  6400000    4.161    0.000   19.818    0.000 demo.py:74(entropy)
 12800000    4.236    0.000   15.657    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
 19301212    6.381    0.000   11.421    0.000 demo.py:77(<genexpr>)
```

Lo que significa:

1. La función que más ha tardado en ejcutarse es `main()`. Tiempo total 94.121s. Vaya novedad :-)
2. La siguiente ha sido el método `_csv.writer`. Ella sola han sido más de 20s, casi la cuarta parte del tiempo total ¡Esto si es interesante! O es que esta función tarda mucho o que se ha llamado muchas veces. De hecho es lo segundo, pues `cPerf` también nos da el número de llamadas, que ha sido 6402000.
3. La siguiente es la función `entropy` que son casi otros 20s. Miraremos después qué pasó aquí. De momento me centraré en el problema del csv.

Como ya te había dicho en un comentario, la escritura del .csv la haces dentro de un bucle, cosa que no se comprende puesto que cada vez que abres el .csv borras el anterior. Y además en todas las iteraciones escribes dentro lo mismo.

Es decir, tu código tiene básicamente esta estructura:

```
for mu in range(len(muestras)):
   for _ in range(simulaciones):
      Realizar simulacion
      Escribir CSV
```

Y yo creo que debería ser:

```
 for mu in range(len(muestras)):
   for _ in range(simulaciones):
      Realizar simulacion
 # Una vez terminadas todas las simulaciones
 Escribir CSV
```

Modifico el código para que haga esto segundo (es decir, desindento todo el bloque `with open(...) as csvfile` para que quede al nivel del `for mu` inicial) y ejecuto de nuevo todo con `cProfile`.

¡¡Caray!! El tiempo total ha bajado a **0.293s**  ¡Menos de medio segundo!

La salida de `cProfile` ha sido ahora:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      5/1    0.000    0.000    0.293    0.293 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.293    0.293 demo3.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.030    0.030    0.277    0.277 demo3.py:79(main)
     2000    0.016    0.000    0.187    0.000 demo3.py:55(jugar)
     8000    0.002    0.000    0.170    0.000 {built-in method builtins.next}
    10000    0.030    0.000    0.169    0.000 demo3.py:22(generar_senales)
```

Dejando de lado que `main()` lógicamente, se lleva el 100% del tiempo de ejecución, lo siguiente que vemos es que de ese tiempo la mayoría se ha invertido en la función `jugar()`, lo cual tiene mucho más sentido. Ya no es la generación del csv lo que se lleva todo el tiempo. Dentro de jugar parece que puede ser `generar_senales` quien más tiempo requiere.

Pero un descenso de 100s a 0.25s es demasiado bueno para ser cierto. ¿Será igual el .csv que genera en este segundo caso? Había renombrado el generado en la ejecución anterior para no perderlo. Lo comparé con el que sale en esta otra ejecucición (usando `diff`). ¡Son idénticos!

Por tanto, éxito total. Si ahora aumento el tamaño de la lista a 200, 300, etc. los tiempos suben a 0.48s, 0.616s, etc. Es decir, el incremento de tiempo parece lineal.

#### Actualización

Aún se podría intentar optimizar más, a ver por qué la función `generar_senales()` tarda tanto. Tras echar un ojo a los resultados del *profiler* determino que se debe a dos causas:

- La función `choice()` que es llamada muchas veces.
- La *comprehension list* que construye la lista de probabilidades antes de llamar a `choice()`.

Ya que en realidad no entiendo el algoritmo que estás ejecutando, no se me ocurre cómo se podría evitar esa *list comprehension*, si es que se puede. Y en cuanto a `choice()` el uso de `bisect()` ya la hace muy eficiente. Probé a cambiarla por `numpy.random.choice()` pero ésta aún tardaba más.

Lo único que se me ocurre es que cuando construyas la lista de probabilidades intentes si es posible crear ya la de probabilidades acumuladas, para evitar tener que calcularlas en `choice()`, pero no veo claro si esto sería posible.

En todo caso sería una ganancia de velocidad menor. No afecta a la complejidad asintótica del problema que ya hemos reducido de O(N²) a O(N).